# English equivalent of Chinese saying "Keep quiet and make big money"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there any English equivalent for the Chinese proverb **“悶聲大發財” (He who keeps silent makes a fortune)**, which implies that *in order to be wealthy and successful you must stay low and mince your words* ?

Comment: *Quiet achiever* carries some of that idea, but quietness isn't a condition there - it just happens to be a quality of the achiever.

Comment: Shut up and get rich.

Comment: Is this what you tell adult film stars before an election?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with reward, not wealth. And I'm also not sure it works, but it's what popped in my head:

the meek shall inherit the earth.

Different wordings are found in different bibles:

> New American Standard Bible 
> "Blessed are the gentle, for they shall
>   inherit the earth.
>
> Christian Standard Bible
>  Blessed are the humble, for they will inherit
>   the earth.

The meaning understood from this line may vary among popular culture, biblical scholars and so forth, but I did find one meaning at dictionary.com:

> The saying implies that those who forgo worldly power will be rewarded
>   in the kingdom of heaven.
>  [The New Dictionary of Cultural
>   Literacy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/the-meek-shall-inherit-the-earth)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn’t explicitly include the “be wealthy and successful” /
“make a fortune” / “make big money” aspect,
but an idiom for “keep quiet, stay low and mince your words”
is ***keep your head down***.

> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/keep-your-head-down):
>
>   to continue doing something quietly,
>     especially when there is trouble happening around you
>   *I have got to keep my head down and play it as it comes.*
>
> [the Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/keep-your-head-down):
>
>   to avoid trouble:
>   *He’s in a bad mood today – I’m just keeping my head down.*
>
> [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+your+head+down):
>
>   To actively avoid conflict or attention.
>   *I’m keeping my head down at work these days
>     because I don’t want to be among the layoffs
>     that are sure to accompany our recent change in leadership.*

Answer (score 0):

This doesn’t explicitly include the “be wealthy and successful” /
“make a fortune” / “make big money” aspect,
but an idiom for “keep quiet, stay low and mince your words”
is ***don’t rock the boat***.

> [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/don%27t+rock+the+boat):
>
>   Don't say or do something that could upset a stable situation.
>   *None of my family members are fighting with each other right now,
>     so please don’t rock the boat
>     by bringing up politics or any other controversial topics.*
>
> [Idioms Online](http://www.idioms.online/rock-the-boat):
>
>   To rock the boat is to do something which causes trouble
>     or upsets a stable or desirable situation.
>   - My supervisor is very abusive
>       but I just got a big raise and I don’t want to rock the boat.
>
>     I really don’t want to rock the boat,
>       but I think someone should say something about Rob’s behavior.
>
> [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Rock%20the%20boat):
>
>   “rocking the boat” means stirring up trouble. 
>     To rock the boat means to disrupt things, promote disharmony,
>     make waves, pick a fight, causing trouble, disagreement...